# How the additional argumentts in JavaScript higher order functions work?

Tags: javascript

I am somewhat confused to how the higher order functions work with additional arguments. Say for example:

```
let Array1 =  [[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5]];

let Array2 = Array1.map(element => {
element[4] = -6;
return element;
},() => {
            //Now this is the part which I need to know
            //function2 execution
           console.log("Hey How does this function work");
});
```

I am interested in knowing the `function2` execution, how does it work? Once the first argument is done execution is that when it goes to the `function2` and what are its uses? How can we take advantage of passing multiple functions? Is it used in `async` processing?

Comment: Your example doesn't really make sense. The assignment `element[11] = …` is indeed not correct, and that second function is never called so it doesn't "work".

Comment: "*Once the first argument is done execution*" - not sure what you mean by that. Do you understand how `map` works normally (with a single function)?

Comment: "*what are its uses?*" - none, it is not used. "*How can we take advantage of passing multiple functions?*" - we don't. "*Is it used in async processing?*" - no, that has nothing to do with it.

Comment: `element[11] = "Not Correct";` in your example ends up being a "no-op" (an operation that ultimately doesn't do anything). Your array elements are numbers, so that statement creates a `Number` object for the number primitive, sets its `"11"` property, and then throws away that object, returning the primitive number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see from the docs in this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), the second argument to `map` function is not another function.
It is called `thisArg` and represents the "Value to use as `this` when executing `callback`".

Comment: On **rare** occasions it can make sense to pass a function as the `thisArg`, but...yeah, not here. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstand about the second argument. It defines `this` that should be used inside the callback function.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

FYI, `element[11] = "Not Correct";` will throw error because `element` is number type.

Comment: No, `element[11] = "Not Correct";` doesn't throw any error. [Explanation here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65449812/how-the-additional-argumentts-in-javascript-higher-order-functions-work#comment115712224_65449812).